# IMO problem 4, $1998$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Determine all pairs $(a, b)$ of positive integers such that $ab^{2} + b + 7$ divides
$a^{2}b + a + b$. I really have no idea where to start with this. This is the first IMO problem that I attempted, because it looked to be the easiest, but I honestly have no idea where to begin. Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: This site contains all solutions to IMO problems from 1959 to 2009 http://www.imomath.com/

Comment: Solutions to IMO problems can usually be found by a Google search. That is true in this case.

Comment: Yea people shouldn't tell that it is an IMO question when asking. That really spoils all the fun knowing where to find the solution.

Comment: Wow, thanks. The solution is pretty short, but I was thinking along the wrong lines. Thank you all for these references!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us give this question an answer. The solution can be found [here](https://prase.cz/kalva/imo/isoln/isoln984.html).

Comment: The link is dead. Do you have another source?

Answer (score 7):

I've got a different solution to the one offered here already.

If $ab^2+b+7 \mid a^2b+a+b$, then $ab^2+b+7 \mid b(a^2b+a+b) - a(ab^2+b+7) = b^2-7a$

Now there are three cases left to check:

1. $b^2-7a = 0$. This yields the infinite set of solutions $(a,b) = (7k^2, 7k)$, where $k\ge1$
2. $b^2-7a > 0$. Hence, we have $ab^2+b+7 \le b^2-7a <b^2< ab^2+b+7$, a contradiction, so no solutions.
3. $b^2-7a < 0$. Hence, we have $ab^2+b+7 \le 7a-b^2 \Rightarrow a(b^2-7) \le -b^2-b-7$. The RHS is negative, and since $a > 0$ we must have $b^2-7 <0 \Rightarrow b=1$ or $2$. Checking these cases individually we get two more solutions: $(a, b) = (11, 1), (49, 1)$.

Therefore, the solutions are $(a, b) = (11, 1), (49, 1), (7k^2, 7k)$

Answer (score 4):

The most fundamental thing you need to know about divisibility is: if d is a divisor of A and d is also a divisor of B, then d will be a divisor of any number of form mA+nB, with m,n integers.

Indeed, $\frac{m*A+n*B}{d} = m*\frac{A}{d}+n*\frac{B}{d}$ is integer :P

Another way to think about our problem is: if $\frac{X}{Y}$ is integer, then $m \cdot \frac{X}{Y}-n$ is an integer too!

---

I will try to follow a more "what the heck I would do here?" approach.

Let $f(a,b)=\cfrac{a^2b+a+b}{ab^2+b+7}$. We want to find all $(a,b)$ such that $f(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If I don't know how to start, then I will just substitute $a$ and $b$ and try to solve particular cases. Obviously, there is no point setting values in both variables at the same time, e.g. verifying if $f(10,20)$ is integer. A better approach is to fix a variable and try to solve the other, e.g. verify if $f(a,1)$ is integer.

What is the better variable to fix, a or b? Well, I don't know for now. Just start with a:

- $f(1,b)=\cfrac{2b+1}{b^2+b+7}$. Oh man, we have a seriously bad guy below! Just think about it: "find all numbers with divisors of the form $b^2+b+7$". It looks like a hard problem!

What if we tried with b=1?

$f(a,1)=\cfrac{a^2+a+1}{a+8}$. Way better!

We could even try a smart substitution like $a=A-8$, couldn't we? Yes, and I encourage you to do that!

But for now we will try something different. What about using the second lemma above? Looking at

$m \cdot \cfrac{a^2+a+1}{a+8} -n$

we can try $m=1, n=a$: $1 \cdot \cfrac{a^2+a+1}{a+8} - a = \cfrac{a^2+a+1-a^2-8a}{a+8} = \cfrac{-7a+1}{a+8}$. Now we can try adding 7:

$ 7 - \cfrac{-7a+1}{a+8} = \cfrac{7a+56-7a+1}{a+8} = \cfrac{57}{a+8}$.

57 can be factored as $3 \cdot 19$, then its divisors are 1,3,19,57. For those, the values of $a$ are $-7,-4,11,49$.

Now we can try $b=2$:

$f(a,2)=\cfrac{4a^2+a+2}{4a+11}$. As before, the idea is to decrease the degree of numerator. If we try to subtract a, we will have

$\cfrac{4a^2+a+2}{4a+11}-a = \cfrac{4a^2+a+2-4a^2-11a}{4a+11} = \cfrac{-10a+2}{4a+11}$

Now multiplying by 4 and adding 10, or even better, multiplying by 2 and adding 5:

$ 2 \cdot \cfrac{-10a+2}{4a+11} + 5 = \cfrac{-20a+4+20a+55}{4a+11} = \cfrac{59}{4a+11}$.

59 is prime, and $59-11=48=4 \cdot 12$, but $f(12,2) = \cfrac{302}{25}$ is not an integer.

Now we will try $b=3$:

$f(a,3)=\cfrac{3a^2+a+3}{9a+10}$

$a- 3 \cdot f(a,3)=\cfrac{7a-9}{9a+10}$. Behold! Obviously $7a-9 < 9a+10$! Then, if $7a-9 >= 0$ then this fraction will be a rational number between 0 and 1, then it not will be an integer!

That way, we can try to test for $7a-9<0$ In this case, $a=1$ is the only possible value, but it fails: -2 is not a multiple of 19!

Now we can go to a more general approach. The idea is to reduce the degree of $a$ above:

$f(a,b)=\cfrac{b \cdot a^2 + 1 \cdot a + b}{b^2 \cdot a + b+7}$

$f(a,b)=\cfrac{b \cdot a^2 + 1 \cdot a + b}{b^2 \cdot a + (b+7)}$

$b \cdot f(a,b)-a = \cfrac{(b^2 \cdot a^2 + b \cdot a + b^2) - (b^2 \cdot a^2 + (b+7) \cdot a)}{b^2 \cdot a + (b+7)} = \cfrac{b^2-7a}{b^2 \cdot a + (b+7)}$

Now that looks a bit interesting! If $b^2=7a$ the numerator is 0 and we obviously have solutions. We have $b=7k,a=7k^2$ and plugging them in the original $f$ we obtain $f(a,b)= k$ is always integer!

Now, what if $b^2-7a$ is not 0? Well, are you noting that the the numerator looks smaller?

If $b^2-7a > 0$, then obviously $ b^2 + "something"$ is asymptotically smaller than $ab^2+"someOtherThing"$. Indeed, in our case it is true even if taken literally: $b^2-7a < b^2 < ab^2 < ab^2+b+7$. Then $b \cdot f(a,b)-a$ will never be an integer.

If $7a-b^2 > 0$, then we can just verify whether $b^2$ is smaller or greater than $7$.

If $b^2 \geq 7$, then $7a-b^2 < 7a \leq b^2a < b^2a+b+7$

If $b^2 < 7$, then $b=1$ or $b=2$, and we already solved these cases!

Therefore, the solutions are $(a,b) \in \{(11,1),(49,1)\} \cup \{(7k^2,7k), k \geq 1\}$